# How to use Contribution Token {contribution.amount_level}?

Tags: civicontribute, tokens, price-sets

The contribution tokens contain the token **{contribution.amount_level}**.
I find this tokens via find contributions -> Email send now
I was hoping this token would return information about the Price Set fields. Unfortunately it returns 'array' testing it.

Can someone please explain how to use this token? I find literally nothing…

My target: We do a little merchandise and publication selling, get 'orders' via Mail, add off-line contributions in CiviCRM (pay later - banking). What we want to do ist sending an Email confirming the order (including the ordererd items) and printing out a cover letter (containing payment instructions). 
Now a price set used for contributions, containing our merchandising items, shipment costs, prices, quantities and so on looks perfect for that purpose - if one could get those price set informations into one simple mail. So I hoped that token would deliver exactly what is shown.

I know there are some topics dealing with tricky smarty operations (which is far beyond my understanding), but nowhere is explained what the {contribution.amount_level} is supposed to do or how to use it.

We are running CiviCRM 4.7.29

Comment: What is it about the standard contribution receipt (which should include line items iirc) that doesn't deliver what you need?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I see now that contribution receipt contains those "line items". I'm not happy with that automated receipt. First, it should not state contribution receipt in this case but "order receipt", "order date" and so on. I'm not sure if it's clever to change this system generated message-template for this special purpose.
Second, we need this lines again when sending the items and adding a nice, friendly, personal cover letter (and not something technical like a fixed and unflexible invoice).
And the quesition is: what about that token, how does it work, why not?

Comment: Maybe the question here should be 'what token should I use'? If you look in your db in the contribution table you will likely see amount_level field is mostly empty.